# injecting files into a git repository without doing a checkout

Tags: git

I am working on a localization framework that managaes the text-assets for several applications (wpf,android,ios) in a library. We use git as the version control system for all the applications. Now I want to export those assets directly into the the git-repository.

The problem is: I dont want to clone/pull the whole repository every time i export the assets into the git repositories. In fact I dont want to know about any files exept those assets. I already figured out that checking out subdirs is not possible with git, but is there a way to "inject" or "force" those changes into the repository without having to pull all the other changes and files? (Note: the assets are only changed here and are not edited by the developers directly)
It should basically ignore everything that happens outside the assets folder.
Another imoportant thing is that it shouldn't change the workflow for our developers, so submodules is not really an option since they would have to pull the submodule all the time.

Is there a good way to do this with git except ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say 'export the assets' are you referring to doing a commit?

Comment: Sure i mean a commit. but i dont want the whole thing with pulling/cloning all the other files. i edited the question so its clearer

Comment: Submodules are the way to accomplish this. Why would your developer's workflow need to change? If the files are needed to compile, make the build script ensure their presence.

Comment: the developers would have to pull the asset-submodule seperatley so its more complicated for them. i want a fail-safe solution for that.

Comment: It can be helpful to slow down and wait to see if other people have an answer before you accept one. I almost didn't post my answer because you already accepted another (fine) answer. I posted it anyway because I think it's an interesting question, but in general, if you want a maximum number of responses, don't be in a hurry. (By the way, I wouldn't be surprised at all if @Borealid's answer is the right one for you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git, a commit object references a *tree object*. That *tree object* then references *blob objects*. Each blob is (generally) a file in your working copy.

The commit identifier is a hash of the commit object, which contains the hash of the tree object, which itself contains the hash of all the blobs.

So, in order to make a commit, **you must know the state of all blobs in the commit**. The commit is, effectively, a snapshot of the **whole** working copy (technically, the index). This means you can't just "ignore changes outside dir X", because if you did that, your commit would produce a working copy either without those files (if you didn't include them in the tree object) or with outdated copies (if you check out once and then assume they're unchanged, putting the outdated hashes into the tree object).

This is why you can't just check out a subtree in git and ignore changes outside of it. This is also why what you're asking for (making a commit without ever looking at the state of other files) is impossible.

However, I think if you were to try the "git way" of doing things - cloning once, then committing many times from that one clone - you would rapidly discover it is a very low-overhead way of doing things.

Failing that, you could make your "assets" be a separate repository (possibly a git submodule, they don't require a significant "change to the developers' workflow", really). Then you only have to clone the "assets" repository to make commits there.

You could also just send patches to the already-up-to-date server and have it do the commits locally. This wouldn't involve ever cloning the repo, since of course the server must have the latest changes to other files (it's the source you'd be pulling from!).

Comment: thanks for the answer! i will use the "git way" then, i just thought there might be a shortcut here that i could use.

Comment: Actually, now you mention it, the Git object model *does* allow you to do commits without having the whole tree checked out. The tree objects are really directory objects; they represent one node in the filesystem tree. If you changed or added a file, you'd need to add a new blob object for it, and add a new tree object for its directory to point to it, and then recursively go up the directory hierarchy adding new tree objects pointing to the new versions of their children, until you get to the root, at which point you create a new commit object. But that's all ...

Comment: ... in particular, you don't need to even look at *any* other tree or blob objects, you just need to know the hashes of some of them, so you can construct tree objects for the directories you're modifying, and you can get the hashes from the old tree objects for those directories.

Comment: However, i'm not aware of a tool which actually does this, so unless the OP feels like doing some fairly heavy-duty programming, your answer is the right one!

Comment: Wait, i've just noticed that @amcnabb's answer describes exactly this process. Nice work!

Comment: @TomAnderson, I'm glad you enjoyed it. Once I wrote the script that did this, I felt like I really "knew" git (even though there are still tons of features I don't know).

Comment: @amcnabb: I can imagine it was a bit like that bit in the Matrix where Neo suddenly sees through the illusion of the world to the truth that underlies it.

Comment: @TomAnderson What I was trying to say is that you cannot safely, without checking the repository to see if other objects have changed, create a new commit. As I said in my answer, you must either remove the blobs' hashes (in which case you have a commit which effectively deletes files) or assume they're the same as the preceding commit (which effectively ignores later changesets). So you must *consider* the blobs. You don't need their actual data, but you do need to check whether there's been a change affecting them...

Comment: @borealid, it's a bit simpler than that. In my procedure, the commit-tree will automatically fail if anything changes, I.e. if a new commit was made while you were prepping your commit. In that case, you just start over. It's very simple and very safe.

Comment: @amcnabb How and why? Since `git commit-tree` is just creating a new tree object, and not doing **anything** to the refs in the repository, how could it know "a new commit was made" (between the `git write-tree` and the `git commit-tree`)? Which commits would qualify as interfering? If I had a repository with ten billion branches, would a commit to any of them cause `git commit-tree` to fail? Incidentally, running `git read-tree` involves looking at the state of files not related to your commit (their hashes), which is what I asserted was necessary.

Comment: Borealid, sorry, I said it wrong earlier. It's the `update-ref` that will automatically fail. So, the `commit-tree` is more than happy to write a tree to the repo, but if any new commit was written in the meantime, the update-ref will fail. If the current head isn't still `$head`, then it fails. I've used this with a few dozen commits happening in parallel, and it works great. With respect to `git read-tree` looking at the state of files, the important thing is that you don't need a working tree.

Comment: hey guys, thanks for the vivid discussion here, didnt expect that :)
i will now use (clone/pull) + commit + push and keep a local version of the repository, since its easy to implement. but as soon as i have a bit more time i will try and update my program to do it the cool way.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to write a script that can inject blobs without having to checkout a working tree, as long as the repository itself is available locally. It's not trivial, though. I have written such a script before, which I'll omit due to its length and its not being publicly available, but basically it involves performing the following git commands in a loop (restarting the loop if anything fails):

```
# Find the current head.
head="$(GIT_DIR="$repo" git show-ref --heads --hash master)"
# Get the current version of the file.
GIT_DIR="$repo" git cat-file blob "$head:path/to/file" >"$tmpdir/tempfile"
# [Modify the file if necessary.]
# Write the blob into the repository.
blob="$(GIT_DIR="$repo" git hash-object -w "$tmpdir/tempfile")"
# Read the tree into an index file.
GIT_INDEX_FILE="$index" GIT_DIR="$repo" git read-tree "$head"
# Add the ref of the blob into the index file.
GIT_INDEX_FILE="$index" GIT_DIR="$repo" git update-index --add \
    --cacheinfo 100644 "$blob" path/to/file
# Write the index file into the repo as a tree.
tree="$(GIT_INDEX_FILE="$index" GIT_DIR="$repo" git write-tree)"
# Write a commit to the repo.
commit="$(echo "autocommit" |GIT_DIR="$repo" git comm   it-tree "$tree" -p "$head")"
# Update the head of the repository to be the new commit.
GIT_DIR="$repo" git update-ref refs/heads/master "$commit" "$head"
```

This isn't complete (I've omitted some error-handling code that restarts the loop), but it's more than pseudocode. Hopefully it's enough to be helpful. This makes for a more complicated script than if you just clone the repository, but it's much, much faster. Which one to use depends on what you need.

By the way, if the repository is on NFS, locking doesn't work correctly, and you have to check for a race condition (your ref could get reset, forcing you to restart the whole process).